# Android Unit Test ViewModel Wanted but not invoked

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-viewmodel

I'm new on unit testing. I'm trying to do unit testing on my view model class but my test fail with error:

*Wanted but not invoked:
toggleMovieFavorite.invoke(
Movie(id=1, title=Title, overview=Overview, releaseDate=01/01/2025, posterPath=, backdropPath=, originalLanguage=ES, originalTitle=Title, popularity=5.0, voteAverage=7.0, favorite=false)
);
-> at xyz.jonthn.usescases.ToggleMovieFavorite.invoke(ToggleMovieFavorite.kt:7)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.*

This is my test file

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class DetailViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    lateinit var findMovieById: FindMovieById

    @Mock
    lateinit var toggleMovieFavorite: ToggleMovieFavorite

    @Mock
    lateinit var observer: Observer<Movie>

    private lateinit var vm: DetailViewModel

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Before
    fun setUp() {

        Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined)

        vm = DetailViewModel(1, findMovieById, toggleMovieFavorite, Dispatchers.Unconfined)
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun `when favorite clicked, the toggleMovieFavorite use case is invoked`() {
        runBlocking {

            val movie = mockedMovie.copy(id = 1)

            whenever(findMovieById.invoke(1)).thenReturn(movie)

            whenever(toggleMovieFavorite.invoke(movie)).thenReturn(movie.copy(favorite = !movie.favorite))

            vm.movie.observeForever(observer)

            vm.onFavoriteClicked()

            verify(toggleMovieFavorite).invoke(movie)
        }
    }

    val mockedMovie = Movie(
    0,
    "Title",
    "Overview",
    "01/01/2025",
    "",
    "",
    "ES",
    "Title",
    5.0,
    7.0,
    false)
}
```

This is my DetailViewModel:

```
class DetailViewModel(
private val movieId: Int, private val findMovieById: FindMovieById,
private val toggleMovieFavorite: ToggleMovieFavorite,
uiDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) : ScopedViewModel(uiDispatcher) {

private val _movie = MutableLiveData<Movie>()
val movie: LiveData<Movie> get() = _movie

init {
    launch {
        _movie.value = findMovieById.invoke(movieId)
    }
}

fun onFavoriteClicked() {
    launch {
        movie.value?.let {
            _movie.value = toggleMovieFavorite.invoke(it)
        }
    }
}
```

}

And my use case ToggleMovieFavorite:

```
 class ToggleMovieFavorite(private val moviesRepository: MoviesRepository) {
    suspend fun invoke(movie: Movie): Movie = with(movie) {
        copy(favorite = !favorite).also { moviesRepository.update(it) }
    }
    }
```

Thank you so much for your help guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

i thougt mockito does not invoke your init method on viewmodel, you should put your declaration of **vm** on each *@test* instead of *@Before* since method *findMovieById* called at init, right before the function is mocked.